# in Google Tag Manager, Trigger type 'Form Submission' works with Google Form submission?

Tags: forms, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, submission

in Google Tag Manager, there is trigger type 'Form Submission'.

I know Google Tag Manager + Google Analytics can track form submissions with this trigger type.
(If it is not, please let me know correct Answer)

I want to know 2 things.

- This trigger type 'Form Submission' works with Google Form submission?
  (I was looking somethings for this, and I knew this is not working.
  But I want to make clear this here.)
- If not, how can I track Google Form Submission?

Best Regards

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, GTM will not track Google Form submissions as long as Google form is embedded as an Iframe. There are several possible workarounds but most of them have specific limitations. One of the solutions is using Zapier ([Use Google Analytics to track Google Form submissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902813/use-google-analytics-to-track-google-form-submissions)) Other is based on Google Apps scripts (in russian https://web-analytics.me/custom_fields_in_google_forms#240085507.1543326351)

Comment: What is the limitation of the way using Zapier?

Comment: Set the trigger to fire when the Page URL contains a unique part of a URL e.g. "/pages/contact." - This URL should be the url of Google Form?

Comment: you need to pass client ID so the submission event would be associated with a relevant session and this is quite tricky and unreliable

Comment: Set the trigger to fire when the Page URL contains a unique part of a URL e.g. "/pages/contact." - This URL should be the url of Google Form?